# getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS for segmentedControl

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting, uisegmentedcontrol

I am running into the EXC_BAD_ACCESS whenever I tap on a segmentedControl in my iphone app.

I am using an OSS libray called PPiFlatSegmentedControl (https://github.com/pepibumur/PPiFlatSegmentedControl). here is my code initializing the segment:

```
- (void)setupSegmentedControl {
  // open source library - PPiFlatSegmentedControl
  PPiFlatSegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[PPiFlatSegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 42, 320, 40) items:@[
                                              @{@"text":@"ALL"},
                                              @{@"text":@"COMPLETED"},
                                              @{@"text":@"UNCOMPLETED"}] iconPosition:IconPositionRight andSelectionBlock:^(NSUInteger segmentIndex) {
                                              switch (segmentIndex) {
                                                  case 0:
                                                       // All
                                                       //[self enableFilters];
                                                       [tasks addObjectsFromArray:[[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] fetchTaskList]];
                                                       break;
                                                  case 1:
                                                        // Complete
                                                        [tasks addObjectsFromArray:[[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] fetchTasksByCompletion:YES]];
                                                        break;
                                                  case 2:
                                                        // Uncompleted
                                                        [tasks addObjectsFromArray:[[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] fetchTasksByCompletion:NO]];
                                                        break;
                                                  default:
                                                  break;
                                               }


                                              }];

  segmentedControl.color=[UIColor colorWithRed:45.0f/255.0 green:203.0f/255.0 blue:116.0f/255.0 alpha:1];
  segmentedControl.borderWidth=0.5;
  segmentedControl.borderColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
  segmentedControl.selectedColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:36.0f/255.0 green:190.0f/255.0 blue:104.0f/255.0 alpha:1];
  segmentedControl.textAttributes=@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13],
                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]};
  segmentedControl.selectedTextAttributes=@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13],
                                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]};
  [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

SO, whenever I tap on one of the cells/buttons I get that error. Keep in mind my project currently doesn't have ARC - so I really have a feeling I am managing the memory incorrectly. If you need anymore information or anything else - please let me know!

-Matt

Comment: Please comment out your `switch` and try again. I want to know if the problem is the segmented control or CoreData. And BTW, if your project is not using ARC then you should `autorelease` the control: `[self.view addSubview:[segmentedControl autorelease]];`

Comment: Try also to define segmentedControl as an ivar.

Comment: Cool, I set it as an ivar, added the [segmentedControl autorelease] & commented out the switch. The error is now -[__NSCFString CGColor]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a97700 - which is weird.. could it be a problem with the library? the error seems to be in UIButton+PPiAwesome.m method:: -(void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor*)color forUIControlState:(UIControlState)state,